# CouchBase synchronous replication?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchbase

I already posted this on a somewhat-related thread ( [Difference between CouchDB and Couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578608/difference-between-couchdb-and-couchbase) ), but would like to make it more easy to google by splitting it to here:

Can someone go into detail regarding the "Optional Synchronous Replication" CouchBase claims to offer. As far as I can tell, the replication offered in Apache CouchDB is eventual/asynchronous, so I am wondering if more light can be shed on the possibility of asych replication, and how it would work.

Also, what specifically do you mean by "Optional"? Is it included in the free enterprise version of CouchBase? What about the non-enterprise?

Cheers and best of luck!

Tim Vaillancourt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578608/difference-between-couchdb-and-couchbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line was accidentally copied from a similar table of features from the Membase Server specs page. It refers to the SYNC command which is new in Membase 1.7. Sorry for the confusion, we've removed the incorrect info from that page.

The word "Optional" doesn't have anything to do with Community vs. Enterprise Edition. It's simply referring to how the feature is used.