# What is the difference between couchbase and couchdb? Are the clients fully interoperable?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchbase

Related: [Difference between CouchDB and Couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578608/difference-between-couchdb-and-couchbase)

It is not clear if the clients and libraries are interoperable.

- Can I use jcouchdb with couchbase?
- Can I use couchbase client libraries with couchdb?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

CouchDB is a backend Database solution. Couchbase is a Caching solution.

The confusion you are running into is that Couchbase 2.0 uses CouchDB as a database back end in place of SQLite.

```
CouchDB: http://couchdb.apache.org/
Couchbase: http://www.couchbase.com/
```

Comment: Couchbase is a database that contains a caching layer, it is not just a caching solution. Couchbase also doesn't provide full CouchDB API compatibility. Some API's are exactly the same, others are different, and some are non-existent.

Comment: Thanks, I know at the high level that Couchbase uses couchdb internally. However, it is still not clear if the client libraries and REST API are fully compatible or not? Aside from installing and trying both myself, is there any info on the Internet about this? I was hoping that Couchbase site would have this info.

Comment: The client SDK's are not fully compatible. The Couchbase clients use a mixture of memcached and http protocol. The CouchDB clients are strictly http.

Comment: Actually this answer at the time it was written was completely accurate. (I can not account for the current state of Couchbase as I have not used it in a number of years.) Couchbase started as a Caching solution, built around implementing a clustered form of Memcache. Then they added CouchDB for better handling of back end replication and features. Since then, as I understand it, they have shifted towards more of a database/datastore solution, but as I said, I have not used it in some time and have little knowledge of where it is now.