# Differences between PouchDB and CouchBase Lite + LiteGap

Tags: cordova, couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-lite

In a Phonegap offline/online project:

- What is the difference between using [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) and using [CouchBase Lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) with the new [LiteGap](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Couchbase-Lite-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin?
- Are they two different solutions to the same problem?
- Can the PouchDB API be used to interact with a local CouchBase Lite database?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After some research and being a relatively new topic, i thought it would be interesting to share my experiences replying my own question:

***What is the difference between using PouchDB and using CouchBase Lite with the new LiteGap plugin?***

PouchDB can create a local database (`websql` or `IndexedDB`) on the device and replicate it with an external CouchDB. Also can be used as a client for an external CouchDB.

Couchbase Lite creates a iOS/Android database on the device, accesible by default on `http://localhost:5984`. You can then replicate the local Couchbase Lite with other external Couchbase/CouchDB services. LiteGap allows you to create and use a Couchbase Lite db in a PhoneGap project.

Both solutions are available to use on a Phonegap project.

***Are they two different solutions to the same problem?***

In short, no.

PouchDB is cross-platform so you can use it in a web project and also in a hybrid app. Also it provides a useful API to interact directly with a local db or external CouchDB. Being based on websql/IndexedDB technologies, you have storage limitations that keep asking the user to allow more local storage space for your web/app.

Couchbase Lite is a native iOS/Android solution that sets a Couchbase database in the device localhost. Together with the LiteGap plugin, you can use it in a Phonegap project.

***Can the PouchDB API be used to interact with a local CouchBase Lite database?***

Yes, but some functionality was not working as expected in my tests.

First, Couchbase Lite has no javascript `HTTP API` so i thought to use Pouch to act just as client. PouchDB can use external Couch services, so we setup Pouch to use the device Couchbase Lite on `localhost:5984`.

Now, with Pouch you can `create` a database, `put()` or `replicate` from local to the cloud. However, i found problems replicating from cloud to local using Pouch's `replicate.from` method. One workaround to that is to setup 2-way replication using good old `$.ajax` to post to the device's `http://localhost:5984/_replicate` as if you were using node `curl` (passing object data with `source`, `target`, `continous` etc..).

I hope this helps to someone taking decisions on which technologies use when creating a offline/online syncable hybrid app.

Comment: "SQLite plugin for Cordova/PhoneGap" from this page: http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html says we no longer need to be aware of quotas etc. B'se PouchDB integrates with SQLite If I'm not wrong!

Answer (score 10):

Just wanted to let you know that I've written an extensive [performance review](http://www.mircozeiss.com/pouchdb-vs-couchbase-lite-a-performance-review) showing the differences between CouchDB and Couchbase Lite.

Some findings:

- PouchDB wins when "adding bulk documents" and "getting an document by id"
- Couchbase Lite wins when "getting all documents"
- they draw when "querying a document via view" (PouchDB is faster but Couchbase Lite has caching)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the 2 other answers, [here](http://blog.couchbase.com/first-steps-with-pouchdb--sync-gateway-todomvc-todolite) is an example application from Couchbase.com blog site, of how to build a todo list application with pouchDB and sync it with CouchBase Mobile.

Another [link](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2015/05/connecting-to-couchbase-with-pouchdb/), on Blackberry developers blog