# Confused with CouchDB and Couchbase

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I'm investigating CouchDB and Couchbase as I am looking for a DB solution for a web application that I will eventually be able to make into a native Android/iOS app as well.  From what I understand, CouchDB/Couchbase excel at being able to use the DB offline and have it synchronize as soon as the connection is restored.

I further understand that CouchDB and Couchbase are 2 distinct products from 2 different organizations - CouchDB is from Apache and Couchbase is from Couchbase.  There is a great response in [SO here explaining some of the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184612/827480).

Couchbase has [Couchbase-Lite-Android](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) and similar for iOS as native embedded DBs for mobile apps which sync with Couchbase server.

Where I get lost is when I try to find the CouchDB equivalent.  Everything points to TouchDB which then says it is no longer actively developed and instead points to Couchbase-Lite-Android as the project that has superceeded it.  But does Couchbase-List-Android/iOS sync with CouchDB or just Couchbase?  According to the Wiki, it indicates that it can sync with CouchDB, but it is a secondary backend which receives lower priority and/or bug fixes.

So then what are the embedded/mobile versions of CouchDB that should be used for Android/iOS?

Comment: The replication protocol used to sync against CouchDB is just that, a protocol http://dataprotocols.org/couchdb-replication/ which e.g. is used b PouchDB which might be of interest to you.

Comment: @Daniel Wow... PouchDB - a JS DB?  Interesting; never heard of it before.  I'll have to look into it more carefully.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "[Couchbase Lite](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/#couchbase-lite)".

I've answered a similar question/confusion over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18055057/1835803).
TouchDB was built to be an Apache-CouchDB compatible database engine suitable for embedding into mobile/desktop apps. The compatible factor here is CouchDB's replication protocol & NoSQL data model.

In a [process](http://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-2011-year-review) to offer mobile synchronization as a feature of Couchbase Server, they altered and renamed TouchDB as Couchbase Lite and also, built [Sync Gateway](https://github.com/couchbase/sync_gateway) to act as a server-side bridge between Couchbase Server and Couchbase Lite.

But the data model & replication protocol are still the same as Apache-CouchDB and Couchbase Lite's replication is entirely compatible with CouchDB.

To conclude, Couchbase Lite <-sync-> Apache-CouchDB & Couchbase Lite <-sync-> (via Sync Gateway) Couchbase Server.

I doubt that CouchDB is a secondary backend which receives lower priority and/or bug fixes. We've been using Couchbase Lite since the days of TouchDB and IMO, Couchbase-Lite is actively developed and greatly supported.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm trying to wade my way into NoSQL world and was getting a little lost between all the different offerings.  Couchbase Lite just made it that much more confusing. :)

Comment: I understand; Even I had been through the same. You can have a look at [FAQ].(https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/wiki/FAQ#compatibility)

Comment: Please note that CouchDB is a primary project that is under active development.  CouchDB is reasonably popular and quite mature. Sorry for the late comment, but the suppositions about CouchDB are incorrect at this time and I felt it important to get accurate information into this thread.