# migrate from CouchDb to Couchbase

Tags: migration, couchdb, couchbase

I'm on development stage and I'm using and enjoying couchDb, mainly because of the 'high' minimum requirements of couchBase.

Anyway I think couchDb is going to be great for the production deployment, but just in case I would like to know if someone of you have *experienced the pains* of migrating from couchDb to couchbase and what are **the steps** to know what I should expect.

I've already read the documentation from couchbase about this specific [migration](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Install/migrate-couchdb.html), and some answers in stackoverflow but not enough insight on this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Couchbase Server is open source too.

Comment: Ok, you're right, I've edited the question; it is open source too, or almost all of it --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578608/difference-between-couchdb-and-couchbase "There are two versions: Community Edition (free but no latest bug fixes) and Enterprise Edition (there are restrictions on usage, confidentiality provisions, audits by Couchbase Inc. that "will be conducted during regular business hours at Licensee's facilities" and other terms typical to proprietary software that many people may find unacceptable)"