# What is the Master node in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

In Couchbase documentation: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/concepts/distributed-data-management.html

> *There is no concept of master nodes, slave nodes, config nodes, name nodes, head nodes, etc, and all the software loaded on each node is identical*

But in my logs I get the message found in post:
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/havent-heard-from-a-higher-priority-node-or-a-master-so-im-taking-over/5924

```
Haven't heard from a higher priority node or a master, so I'm taking over.  mb_master 000   ns_1@10.200.0.10    1:07:38 AM Tue Feb 7, 2017
```

and

```
Somebody thinks we're master. Not forcing mastership takover over ourselves mb_master 000   ns_1@10.200.0.10    1:07:28 AM Tue Feb 7, 2017
```

I am having trouble finding what the master does, because any search about a master results in the comment of couchbase not having a master node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages seem to originate from the cluster management which should look like [this](https://github.com/membase/ns_server/blob/master/src/mb_master.erl) (I didn't manage to find the Couchbase implementation of it). The link points to the implementation of membase which is the [predecessor of Couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184612/2439890).

While all nodes are equal in Couchbase this is **not** the case when there is some redistribution of data. As described in detail in this [document](https://github.com/couchbase/ns_server/blob/master/doc/rebalance-flow.txt) a master is chosen to manage the redistribution. The log messages you get are caused by this process.

Answer (score 1):

The Master Node in the cluster manager is also known as the orchestrator.

Straight from the Couchbase Server 4.6 documentation, https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/concepts/distributed-data-management.html

> Although each node runs its own local Cluster Manager, there is only
>   one node chosen from among them, called the orchestrator, that
>   supervises the cluster at a given point in time. The orchestrator
>   maintains the authoritative copy of the cluster configuration, and
>   performs the necessary node management functions to avoid any
>   conflicts from multiple nodes interacting. If a node becomes
>   unresponsive for any reason, the orchestrator notifies the other nodes
>   in the cluster and promotes the relevant replicas to active status.
>   This process is called failover, and it can be done automatically or
>   manually. If the orchestrator fails or loses communication with the
>   cluster for any reason, the remaining nodes detect the failure when
>   they stop receiving its heartbeat, so they immediately elect a new
>   orchestrator. This is done immediately and is transparent to the
>   operations of the cluster.