# Data base with unicode support for cross-platform mobile application

Tags: database, react-native, mobile, unicode, cross-platform

I am rewriting my app for **iOS** using **react-native** in order to support both Android and iOS platforms.
I have tried **Realm** as a database and have faced with **lack of unicode support** for react-native.
On iOS I used core data and everything was ok.

Are there any database for react-native with unicode support?
What is usual/useful pattern when introducing a database to a cross-platform mobile application? Should I add it on the highest level, for all platforms, or should I do it separately for each platform?

**Update:**
Realm team officially told me that there is no unicode support for react-native(https://forums.realm.io/t/issue-with-requests-containing-unicode-characters/994?u=spineight)

Comment: Not sure why you're facing errors with Realm as it definitely supports Unicode in its other platforms, and I don't see why the JavaScript version would be an exception. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/) for options on storing data in your application.

Comment: @BrunoEly hello I got official answer from Realm team that there is no support of unicode for react-native (https://forums.realm.io/t/issue-with-requests-containing-unicode-characters/994?u=spineight)

Comment: oh that's really interesting, I must have missed it under limitations... Still there's plenty of options out there that do support Unicode (see the question I linked) like SQLite for example

Comment: @BrunoEly are you sure that SQLite supports unicode? No info about it in official site, I have put request for that. My idea is to make sure from official source that unicode is supported when start implementation in order to reduce time spent for that. I have looked through this list many times before, unfortunately there are no info whether unicode is supported that is why I posted this question

Answer (score 0):

From the [link you shared](https://forums.realm.io/t/issue-with-requests-containing-unicode-characters/994/2), Unicode is in fact supported by Realm, although [it does not support case insensitive matching for characters outside of the range UTF-8 0–591](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#limitations-general):

> 5. String sorting and case insensitive queries are only supported for character sets in ‘Latin Basic’, ‘Latin Supplement’, ‘Latin Extended A’, ‘Latin Extended B’ (UTF-8 range 0-591).

As long as you set the encoding to UTF-8 in SQLite, it should let you use SQL `LIKE` statements, with the help of the `UPPER()` and `LOWER()` functions, to do case-insensitive comparing (although the same effect can potentially be achieved in JavaScript and Realm). See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rhomobile/vhDVrfy2fqU).