# Update application on Google play store with new application using react-native

Tags: react-native, google-play

I already have an application it's working and running on google play store using Android java , now I update the same application with react-native the whole app is changed , what options do I have to use the same account for my old app and can we update the application with the new one ? and what ill happen after the update especially if there is internal data saved?

Comment: So you want to know if once updated, the old version of the App can still be used on Play Store? Or are you asking how to update an App?

Comment: I'm asking what will happen to the old data saved once the old users do the update ?

Comment: Was it using RN before?

Comment: No it was regular android app

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible to migrate unless it's stored in a Cloud service or SQLite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android

Answer (score 1):

As long as the application:

- is built to an APK or App Bundle
- has the same package name / application id
- has the same signing certificate

then Google Play doesn't care what language your app was built with, you can just replace one APK with another.

As with any update, internal data is stored on [app specific local storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal). You will have to write code in the new React app to read saved code from the Java app. How hard this is depends on how you wrote the internal saved data.