# What are my options for storing data when using Flutter? (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am still new to the Flutter environment and find it hard to find information about storage options when building an app with Flutter.

Similarly to what [has been asked for react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android), I would like to know what my options are with respects to

- Data persistence
- Remote or locale
- Offline behavior (if applicable)
- Database security
- App performance
- Pricing
- Real time sync
- Compatibility with third party libraries, and Flutter modules
- Anything else...

I have searched the [flutter packages for database](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=database) but did not find it so helpful. Any answer, guide and reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try sqlite?

Comment: While the question is well written, it doesn't belong to SO there's no finite answer. This should be more the topic of a medium post or similar. Not a SO question.

Comment: like react native, you can use firebase. google flutter firebase.

Comment: take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369633/how-can-i-save-to-local-storage-using-flutter/50849802#50849802)

Comment: Your link is actually quite helpful,  perhaps sort the list by score and click thru the top 5.  (the sqflite one even has example code)

Comment: @RémiRousselet I hesitated a lot before posting it but what convinced me to do it is that the react native one was not, got a lot of attention (upvotes and bounty to the answer), which means that the community has a clear interest in that question. Now, I do understand your comment in the scope of SO. How would you proceed? Closing now is an option but wouldn't allow the community to benefit from answers

Comment: Yeah I got surprised the RN worked out. There are many similar questions that are closed daily afterall. Maybe you can change the question to a "How to use X in flutter". And possibly other questions such as "what is the difference between X and Y?".

Comment: Great question. I am only interested in finding an ORM for flutter as this would solve the database issue. With a funcitoning ORM you would be able to use any database there is.

Comment: I can't downvote a comment so doing it in text - disagree strongly with  Rémi Rousselet. I think SO *is* the right place to ask "what are my options". The OP is not asking for a comparative judgement of "best" just a list of what is available now and any hard facts such as performance.

Comment: you can use, Hive - offline NoSQL storage

Answer (score 6):

I have one opensource project on GitHub make sure to check out -

[A flutter project with Implementation of a Contacts app in 4 ways (API, Custom, Preferences and Sqflite).](https://github.com/harsh159357/contacts)

In this Sample Project, there are 4 ways which I have used to store data in flutter which are as follows -

1. REST API ->  (You can store your Data on Server and Perform CRUD Operations with REST APIs)
   [HTTP Package for REST APIs Integration in Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http)
2. Preferences ->   (Store your Data in Shared Preferences)
   [Shared Preferences Package in Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences)
3. Sqlite ->   (Store your Data in SQLite Database)
   [Sqflite Package in Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite)
4. Custom ->   (Store your Data in temporary objects but it will only be accessible during app runtime)

Comment: Hi, how can I achieve the fourth point i.e Store your Data in temporary objects but it will only be accessible during app runtime any example?

Comment: @VijayAnkith check the source code of the following repo - https://github.com/harsh159357/contacts

Comment: Rest api. Is it easy to deal with images storing?

Comment: @RokasDevolskis rest api is the easy way to store images but in my sample project i did it in the BLOB way (In which you can store images directly in the tables in database). But i might suggest you to use some image hosting service for image storing and use that image hosting service image url  to be saved in your table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shared_preferences` as an equivalent to React Native **Async Storage**, you  can read more [here](https://flutter.io/cookbook/persistence/key-value/).
`sqflite` is a good approach for having a local database for offline use.
You can use the [firebase](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/packages?q=firebase) plugins for online data storage and synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

To store a large database you can use SQFlite Helper that is explained [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/07/flutter-sqlite-database-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I used to work on the Realm Xamarin team and am currently using Realm in both a Xamarin Forms app and Swift app, so when I started musing Flutter looked into it.

Realm as of 2018-12 doesn't support Flutter for the same reason that any other C-based data engine will struggle - the problem being poor support in Flutter, as per [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053).

A necessary first step is probably the [Dart VM FFI issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34452).

There's a long [issue tracker thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/55) on the request to add this to Realm and [forum discussion](https://forum.realm.io/t/realm-for-flutter-io/171).

Unsurprisingly, there's currently [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) and SQLite support.