# Realm create offline database and insert data manually - react native

Tags: react-native, realm

Create offline only database, which contains text. Need to insert data manually. App only read and display data

Comment: check this link https://reactnativecode.com/insert-data-into-realm-local-database/

Comment: @PratiusDubey, thankz for the reply. Is there any way to implement the database first like mySQL, because app does only read and display text from the db. There is no any insert, update functions.

Comment: Let me explain in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage offline functionalities with full RDMS it's may not be achievable in any Phone app platform. because there is no Data part implemented in any phone. But we can achieve by Web API and other stuff. And apart from this for  local/offline database management below are support lightweight Database by React Native.

1. Realm
2. Firebase
3. SQLite
4. Core Data
5. PouchDB
6. Async Storage(not a full scale database, but still quite popular).
7. MongoDB.
8. Xml(File management).
9. Json(File management).

And these are all not fully database where we can't write all function of database like Data Definition Language (DDL),Data Manipulation Language (DML).

[For full definition of offline database please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android)

[Check Full offline Implementation](https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline)

I hope it will be helpful...