# The right approach to store unchangeable data in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm about to start an app using reactive native(for iOS and android) and would like to know what's the best approach to store unchangeable data (the user will not insert anything into the app, just read the data). Basically I'm going to develop a Portuguese dictionary, so the app will have to load a lot of data every time the user opens the app. 
Was looking into some options like redux, sqlite, realm etc.. here [What are my options for storing data when using React Native? (iOS and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android), but as my app will not be connecting to an api in order to collect the data, but load all the data from the internal device I wonder the best approach for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the fastest and easiest solution will be Realm, but it's a rather subjective question

Comment: Why not just save it as a JSON file or an array of objects?

Comment: @stever never thought about it, at first thought of having a "map" with key being the  word and the translation of the word being the value. Will make some research about the json stuff. Thanks for the insights!