# Perform CRUD Operation In React Native Using AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-native, react-native-ios

```
  *// Creating An Array
    const someArray = [1,2,3,4];
    return AsyncStorage.setItem('somekey', JSON.stringify(someArray))
    .then(json => console.log('success!'))
     .catch(error => console.log('error!'));



   //Reading An Array 
   return AsyncStorage.getItem('somekey')
  .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(error => console.log('error!'));
   *
```

How Can I Update a Specific Index Of Array And Delete an index
 e.g, new Array should be {1,A,3}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AsyncStorage, it's best if you treat the data structure as immutable. So basically, to perform an update, you grab what you want, mess with it however, and put it back under the same key.

```
return AsyncStorage.getItem('somekey')
  .then(req => JSON.parse(req))
  .then(json => {
          const temp = json;
          temp[2] = 'A';
          temp.pop(); // here it's [1, A, 2]
          AsyncStorage.setItem('somekey', JSON.stringify(temp));
       })
  .catch(error => console.log('error!'));
```

And then to remove any item, just do `AsyncStorage.removeItem('somekey')`. There are no direct operations with `AsyncStorage` to let you do deeper updates, just a key/value data sets.

Comment: Can I Perform CRUD Operation Using Realm or any other database.If you have such example please share it. It will help me with my assignment. I Need Only Simple Array CRUD operation......

Comment: There are implementations where people use AsyncStorage, and a service manages that in the cloud basically, and Realm seems like one of them. If you want a full scale backend at your disposal, check out Firebase - it's not that hard to slap into an application.

Comment: Please check this answer for some data storage options in react native https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android