# How to switch navigation tab after authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learnin React Native and trying to build a small application. I am using below navigation to show login screen to user (if not logged in) or other tabs (if logged in)..

```
{isLoggedIn == null
          ? <Stack.Navigator>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                options={{headerShown: false}}
                component={Login}
              />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          : <Tab.Navigator>
              <Tab.Screen
                name="Home"
.......
........ rest code
```

However this is working fine. But now how can I refresh the complete window (after login) and show the bottom tab navigation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are asking how do you remember if the user is logged in? You'll need to use some form on persistent storage such as [AsyncStorage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage). Then when the window reloads (or loads on a first time), load that storage with your app and properly set the `isLoggedIn` state.

Here is a thread on persistent storage:

[What are my options for storing data when using React Native? (iOS and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android)

Likely you will have a Provider and Context to read from local storage and handle the status of a user being logged in or not. This is also true because many components throughout your app may need this information or `username`

When app opens -> Read storage (you may need to show a loading screen while this loads, it should be fast though). If user is logged in, set up credentials and proper state. If he's not, set it `isLoggedIn` to false.

Consumers can read this context whenever they need data like `username` or `isLoggedIn`.

Comment: thanks, but I know how to remember if user is logged in. But the above code I have written is in App.js (main entry). I want to know how to reload the App.js (I mean main entry) after login is successful ... Now what is happening that, after login, I need to exit app and start again, then only bottom tab navigations are showing..