# How to store data in local storage with react native?

Tags: database, react-native, redux

I want to create todo list with notes with react native and redux. I have complicated logic of storing notes and todos in different places, with different statuses. How should I store all relations and all data in local storage in Android/IOS devices?

Comment: you should avoid storing all data in local storage. it has some memory limit!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are my options for storing data when using React Native? (iOS and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async Storage can only store string data, so in order to store object data you need to serialize it first. For data that can be serialized to JSON you can use JSON.stringify() when saving the data and JSON.parse() when loading the data.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Storing string value

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', value)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

Sorting Object Value

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
 try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

Reading String Value

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
   }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Reading Object Value

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you would use something like https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

However, be aware of AsyncStorage limitations such as encryption and size.

You can use it like that:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

export default {
  setItem: async (key, value) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (error) {}
  },
  getItem: async (key) => {
    try {
      const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);

      return JSON.parse(item);
    } catch (error) {}
  },
  removeItem: async (key) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
    } catch (error) {}
  },
  updateItem: async (key, value) => {
    try {
      const item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      const result = {...JSON.parse(item), ...value};

      await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(result));
    } catch (error) {}
  },
};
```