# React Native Store User Data Local

Tags: react-native, local, user-data

I want to store e.g. the password and the username of the user locally, that the user doesn't always need to log in again.

I just saw the tutorial **[How to store data in local storage with react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154940/how-to-store-data-in-local-storage-with-react-native)** but is there no way, to store a json with data in e.g. a normal folder. What are the benefits or are the benefits?

**Example**:

```
user {
     "name":"max",
     "password":"123456"
}
```

(I know storing passwords in plain text isn't that smart, it is just an example :D)

## Edit

Is there maybe a way to have like a SQL Database locally on the users device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React Native **[Async-Storage](https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage)** is very good. It uses a SQLite database on the users device and it is fast. Maybe you need to change the max storage size for android in a pure android file, but otherwise it works fine. To get data from the database you do something like this:

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
    return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    console.log("There was an error")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a SQLite Database on the users phone. Than you can store things like this:

| username | age | logged-in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john_doe | 13 | true |