# React Native store userdata locally

Tags: react-native, mobile, storage

I want to store e.g. the password and the username of the user locally, that the user doesn't always need to log in again.

I just saw the tutorial [How to store data in local storage with react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154940/how-to-store-data-in-local-storage-with-react-native) but is there no way, to store a json with data in e.g. a normal folder. What are the benefits or are the benefits? How does it look like when compiling the app? Could there be an error? :)

**Example**:

```
user {
     "name":"max",
     "password":"123456"
}
```

(I know storing passwords in plain text isn't that smart, it is just an example :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use AsyncStorage. It can store json data as well as normal data too locally.
If you're working on to add "Remember login" the use this logic - as soon as the user logins in the app, store the data in AsyncStorage with `AsyncStorage.setItem()`

**DemoLogin.js**

```
login = (
    username,
    password,
  ) => {
    axios
      .post(apiEndPoint + "login", {
        username,
        password,
      })
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (response.data) {
          if (response.data.success) {
            this.storeData(response.data);
            this.props.navigation.replace("HomeScreen");
          } else {
            toast.show(response.data.message);
          }
        } else {
          toast.show("There is some issue with API");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        toast.show("There is some issue with API");
      });
  };

storeData = async (userData) => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("userdata", JSON.stringify(userData));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error while storing data", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it soon :D

Answer (score 0):

You can with this [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) package. To storage the username and password is not a good solution like you know. AsyncStorage is usefull to store the data of user for the context of the application. Store file is good if is an image or a specific file like PDF, etc..., where is a lot of data to store. AsyncStorage or the other secure storage has a limit on the size data you can save.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it soon :D