# {React native}, Offline mobile app , sotore data in user device

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native and currently aiming to make a simple ios application using react-native.

The developing application basically stores pre-installed 100 types of text files and other 100 types of text data that users can personally add after installation.

My question is that should 'react-native-SQLite-storage' be used to store data on a user's mobile app?

I have done some research and figured out two ways to store data, one is to use Async Storage, another one is to use react-native-SQLite-storage, and still confusing the difference between those ways.

I appreciate some ideas from people who have been developed react native app before.
Thanks.

Comment: did you look at this post ? It could be helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are my options for storing data when using React Native? (iOS and Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44376002/what-are-my-options-for-storing-data-when-using-react-native-ios-and-android)

Comment: Thanks guys. Appriciate that. it is all clear now.
@Drik

Comment: @sultanaslam
Thanks I got it.